'Out the way' vs 'Out of the way'
Is there any difference between 'out the way' and 'out of the way'? I mean, for instance, shouting at someone standing in you way when you're running.

Can you please cite actual use of the former?

@tchrist: I think this is a context where even if of is partially or completely suppressed, the written version might still show it. I mean because "Get out the way!" looks stranger than it sounds. It might be worth checking Youtube to find a case where of is missing or barely present in the audio. We have to bear in mind that native speakers often hear underarticulated (but expected) elements that non-Anglophones completely miss. Whatever - I think the question is sound, even though maybe it would be better on ELL.

Interestingly, the top answer on what I thought at first might be a duplicate distinguishes between 1) "Out of the fridge" describes an extraction process and 2) "Out of control" uses a different meaning, indicating going outside or beyond. Which at first glance would suggest of CAN'T be discarded in OP's context here. You can get a beer out the fridge in speech, but nobody ever says the situation is out control, and getting out the way sure looks like "going outside or beyond" to me.

Searching Google Books, some of the top uses are about the Lincoln vs Douglas presidential race, and the rallying cry "Get out the way Stephen Douglas ! Get out the way Stephen Douglas ! Get out the way Stephen Douglas ! Lincoln is the man we want to serve us !" This is patterned after the minstrel song "Old Dan Tucker." ...

... Despite the charicatured Black English of its lyrics, other more modern results show it in genuine African-American (or, in one case, South African) use. Outside of these contexts it would be rare.

As it happens, the speaker in Ricky Gervais Extras S01E05 (featuring Samuel L. Jackson) is black, but she's a clear-spoken Brit, no suggestion of AAVE. And at 10:12 she says "Get out the way". That's exactly the orthography in my subtitle file, but when I listen carefully, I'm sure I detect an underarticulated 've = of after out. Sadly, I can't find that one on Youtube. But lets not forget there's a huge difference in meaning between Get out here! and Get out of here!, so whether it's here or the way is obviously significant.

Characterizing the omission of of here as "typically AAVE" is hopelessly misleading, I think.

...there's also Get out the bloody way, whoever you are at 3:27 in Extras S02E01. Again, no Youtube link. I guess that's just because it's the same scriptwriter and/or subtitler, rather than indicating the usage is particularly British, or "Gervaisish".

Eye-dialect  'Get outta the way!' (as mentioned by FF below) with the schwa anywhere between full and zero is a fair representation of an urgent imperative.

No. If you were out of breath and in a hurry you might well leave out the 'of', with no change in meaning.

In rapid casual speech, contracted / unstressed 've = of in Get out've the way! might not be heard by the audience even if the speaker (vaguely) intended to articulate it. But casual speech is more likely to reduce it to Get outta the way! anyway (where of is just reduced to a schwa).

...thinking about it, I actually find it difficult to imagine being shooed away with fully articulated Get out of here! It's always Get outta here!

The only difference is that including of is more careful speech while excluding it is looser, but it’s very minimal. Kind of like the difference between what’s he doing and what is he doing.
It doesn’t just apply with the phrase out of the way. You could also say It fell out (of) my window for instance, and it applies to off too: her hands were off (of) the steering wheel.
Some commenters seem to be expressing doubt that this is actually used by natives, but in my own dialect (middle-class England) it’s very normal - doesn’t even sound improper.
I suspect it originates from a combination of the schwa in outta being quiet, and analogy with other prepositions such as up, down and inside not needing of: e.g. went inside the house or fell down the stairs.
(Edit: Actually I reckon out the way might be more common in British English because we use a glottal /t/ so outta the sounds very similar to out the whereas North Americans pronounce the /t/ as a flap in outta but as an unreleased stop in out the, so they sound quite different)

Yes, I've heard "out of the way" used by Brits in fast speech or not but not in AmE, where people say:  outof the way. :)

Your example with off is back to front: in that case it is off which is standard and off of which is non-standard. I was going to suggest that the use of out as a preposition might be influenced by off of as a sort of "reverse analogy" or hypercorrection; but realising that the only phrases I can think of with out as a prerposition are out the door, out the window and out the way, I think your last suggestion is more likely.


Is there any difference between 'out the way' and 'out of the way'?

Please give full sentences as examples. The full sentence here is "Get out [of] the way!"
(i) of the way is prepositional phrase modifying the phrasal verb "get out", which means to exit or leave.
Without the preposition, the way can be seen as
(ii) a noun phrase acting as an adverbial objective. (Basically, the same as (i))
(iii) the direct object of "to get out"
and
(iv) out can be seen as a preposition whose object is the way thus creating an adverbial modifying "Get".
How you see either sentence will depend on the grammar you are being taught/have learned.
